# How does the browser render array.map() elements if it's just an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, innerhtml

If array.map() returns a new array how does the browser render this properly - it's just an array right?

```
let myArray = [5,6,7];

let newArray = myArray.map( item => `<h2>${item * 2}</h2>`);
```

If i properly understand the map() method, shouldn't the value for the newArray variable be

```
[<h2>10</h2>, <h2>12</h2>, <h2>14</h2>]

document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = newArray;
```

How come this evaluates the code properly in the DOM and lists out every item in array without actually going into the array or listing out a for each?

From what I understand shouldn't the value of body after running the above be [object Object]?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "without actually going into the array". I'm not sure what you mean by "render it correctly", either; if you run this it doesn't render "correctly" by *my* definition: https://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/zq7gedfj/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: In checking the return value i see that its actually a string so I can see how it gets properly rendered by the browser, but W3 says array.map() returns a new array.

Comment: @Adarsh I'm not sure I get the point--OP explicitly states what the array value will be (delta the quotes around the strings), seems like he knows what `map` does

Comment: @Mike It is most certainly not a string, it is an array. And it is *not* "rendered correctly". Unless you explicitly wanted commas between the `<h2>`s, I mean. You're *forcing* it to the default string representation of an array because `innerHtml` expects an HTML string. `console.log(newArray.toString())` should clear this right up.

Comment: @DaveNewton I made some edits to my question. if array.map() returns an array even if it is an array of strings. The browser still seems render each item in the new array individually. But if i insert a array into the dom (innerHTML = newArray) i'm still just adding a javascript array which is an object... does this make sense?

Comment: @Mike No. It "renders each item in the new array individually" because it's coerced to a string. That string is `"<h2>10</h2>,<h2>12</h2>,<h2>14</h2>"`. That's valid HTML that contains three `<h2>` tags and some commas. Why *wouldn't* it render that? If it was "rendering each item _individually_, e.g., iterating over an *array*, it wouldn't render the commas. Which it does. Can you just look at the fiddle and the console output?

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for your response. I see that my confusing wasn't with the array or the map() method itself but with the value that innerHTML is expecting.